# Is it possible to copy a KClass and change it's properties?

Tags: kotlin, reflections, kotlin-reflect

What I'd like to do is use Kotlin reflection to make a copy of a class and set all of it's properties optional/nullable.

E.g.

```
    fun looseClass(schema: KClass<*>): KClass<*> {
        val props = schema.memberProperties.map {
            if(!it.returnType.isMarkedNullable) {
                it.returnType.copy(isMarkedNullable = false)
            }
        }
        
        return schema.copy(memberproperties = props)
    }
```

Obviously the KClass and the KType do not have the `copy` method. Is there any way to achieve what I'd like to do?

Comment: So you want to create a new class dynamically at runtime?

Comment: Yes basically, that is what I want to do. I guess I could also write some compile time code generation with annotation preprocessors, but in this case I have a reason to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I believe this is impossible without some weird hacks, but anyway, what is your use case? If you would create a class at runtime, then you couldn't really use it in the code, because your code would not "see" it. You would have to use this class with reflection as well.